# Fetching coordinates from Http into an array

Tags: flutter

I need to fetch a set of coordinates from an http request and feed it into an array I've defined and draw markers in Google Maps. Below are my codes:

```
final List<LatLng> _markerLocations = [
    LatLng(3.082519, 101.592201),
    LatLng(3.081758, 101.583433),
    LatLng(3.079726, 101.581876),
    LatLng(3.082197, 101.589534),
    LatLng(3.073675, 101.593028)
  ];
```

```
_initMarkers() async {
    final List<MapMarker> _markers = [];

    for (LatLng markerLocation in _markerLocations) {
      // final BitmapDescriptor markerImage =
      //     await MapHelper.getMarkerImageFromUrl(_markerImageUrl);

      _markers.add(
        MapMarker(
          id: _markerLocations.indexOf(markerLocation).toString(),
          position: markerLocation,
          icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
        ),
      );
    }

    _clusterManager = await MapHelper.initClusterManager(
      _markers,
      _minClusterZoom,
      _maxClusterZoom,
    );

    await _updateMarkers();
  }
```

This is the body of the http request:

```
{
    "status": true,
    "statusMsg": null,
    "errorCode": null,
    "body": {
        "rondaLoopCheckpointsList": [
            {
                "pkRondaLoopCheckpointsId": "11f1c165-5647-44d4-a2fd-1d4c8071f5f7",
                "rondaLoop": {
                    "pkRondaLoopId": "42ef5505-e739-45f1-bff3-194d9e1329d5",
                    "company": {
                        "pkCompanyId": "f77819c5-97b8-41be-a745-33f907353e9e",
                        "name": null,
                        "phone": null
                    },
                    "section": {
                        "pkSectionId": "2cd43029-71aa-43a4-8aa2-7e2fbf1ecb1f",
                        "company": null,
                        "sectionNumber": null,
                        "sectionName": "C6",
                        "description": null,
                        "region": null,
                        "mapcenter": null,
                        "mapzoom": null
                    },
                    "name": "SHA-USJ(LOOP1)",
                    "description": "Shah Alam - USJ"
                },
                "checkpoints": {
                    "pkCheckpointId": "8b915f65-b4d1-4cf5-81e7-796d943fe7ab",
                    "company": {
                        "pkCompanyId": "f77819c5-97b8-41be-a745-33f907353e9e",
                        "name": null,
                        "phone": null
                    },
                    "section": {
                        "pkSectionId": "2cd43029-71aa-43a4-8aa2-7e2fbf1ecb1f",
                        "company": null,
                        "sectionNumber": null,
                        "sectionName": "C6",
                        "description": null,
                        "region": null,
                        "mapcenter": null,
                        "mapzoom": null
                    },
                    "cardinalDirection": {
                        "key": 293,
                        "value": "N/A",
                        "description": "Tidak Berkenaan"
                    },
                    "locationType": {
                        "key": 49,
                        "value": "O/H Bridge Restaurant",
                        "description": null
                    },
                    "kilometerMarker": 8.50,
                    "latitude": "3.03000000",
                    "longtitude": "101.58000000",
                    "name": "USJ OBR"
                },
                "sequence": 6
            },
            {
                "pkRondaLoopCheckpointsId": "4000600c-e376-4412-94ad-bd13b454b126",
                "rondaLoop": {
                    "pkRondaLoopId": "42ef5505-e739-45f1-bff3-194d9e1329d5",
                    "company": {
                        "pkCompanyId": "f77819c5-97b8-41be-a745-33f907353e9e",
                        "name": null,
                        "phone": null
                    },
                    "section": {
                        "pkSectionId": "2cd43029-71aa-43a4-8aa2-7e2fbf1ecb1f",
                        "company": null,
                        "sectionNumber": null,
                        "sectionName": "C6",
                        "description": null,
                        "region": null,
                        "mapcenter": null,
                        "mapzoom": null
                    },
                    "name": "SHA-USJ(LOOP1)",
                    "description": "Shah Alam - USJ"
                },
                "checkpoints": {
                    "pkCheckpointId": "8b915f65-b4d1-4cf5-81e7-796d943fe7ab",
                    "company": {
                        "pkCompanyId": "f77819c5-97b8-41be-a745-33f907353e9e",
                        "name": null,
                        "phone": null
                    },
                    "section": {
                        "pkSectionId": "2cd43029-71aa-43a4-8aa2-7e2fbf1ecb1f",
                        "company": null,
                        "sectionNumber": null,
                        "sectionName": "C6",
                        "description": null,
                        "region": null,
                        "mapcenter": null,
                        "mapzoom": null
                    },
                    "cardinalDirection": {
                        "key": 293,
                        "value": "N/A",
                        "description": "Tidak Berkenaan"
                    },
                    "locationType": {
                        "key": 49,
                        "value": "O/H Bridge Restaurant",
                        "description": null
                    },
                    "kilometerMarker": 8.50,
                    "latitude": "3.03000000",
                    "longtitude": "101.58000000",
                    "name": "USJ OBR"
                },
                "sequence": 4
            },
            {
                "pkRondaLoopCheckpointsId": "522c066f-3c59-46e7-9bec-9f2de955874d",
                "rondaLoop": {
                    "pkRondaLoopId": "42ef5505-e739-45f1-bff3-194d9e1329d5",
                    "company": {
                        "pkCompanyId": "f77819c5-97b8-41be-a745-33f907353e9e",
                        "name": null,
                        "phone": null
                    },
                    "section": {
                        "pkSectionId": "2cd43029-71aa-43a4-8aa2-7e2fbf1ecb1f",
                        "company": null,
                        "sectionNumber": null,
                        "sectionName": "C6",
                        "description": null,
                        "region": null,
                        "mapcenter": null,
                        "mapzoom": null
                    },
                    "name": "SHA-USJ(LOOP1)",
                    "description": "Shah Alam - USJ"
                },
                "checkpoints": {
                    "pkCheckpointId": "3566c7ba-6ac4-4e07-b035-f50a5ca53702",
                    "company": {
                        "pkCompanyId": "f77819c5-97b8-41be-a745-33f907353e9e",
                        "name": null,
                        "phone": null
                    },
                    "section": {
                        "pkSectionId": "2cd43029-71aa-43a4-8aa2-7e2fbf1ecb1f",
                        "company": null,
                        "sectionNumber": null,
                        "sectionName": "C6",
                        "description": null,
                        "region": null,
                        "mapcenter": null,
                        "mapzoom": null
                    },
                    "cardinalDirection": {
                        "key": 293,
                        "value": "N/A",
                        "description": "Tidak Berkenaan"
                    },
                    "locationType": {
                        "key": 51,
                        "value": "Toll Plaza",
                        "description": null
                    },
                    "kilometerMarker": 9.00,
                    "latitude": "3.03000000",
                    "longtitude": "101.58000000",
                    "name": "USJ T/P"
                },
                "sequence": 5
            },
            {
                "pkRondaLoopCheckpointsId": "8a0f7e2b-5f8b-4d52-bfb5-846910c8e8c3",
                "rondaLoop": {
                    "pkRondaLoopId": "42ef5505-e739-45f1-bff3-194d9e1329d5",
                    "company": {
                        "pkCompanyId": "f77819c5-97b8-41be-a745-33f907353e9e",
                        "name": null,
                        "phone": null
                    },
                    "section": {
                        "pkSectionId": "2cd43029-71aa-43a4-8aa2-7e2fbf1ecb1f",
                        "company": null,
                        "sectionNumber": null,
                        "sectionName": "C6",
                        "description": null,
                        "region": null,
                        "mapcenter": null,
                        "mapzoom": null
                    },
                    "name": "SHA-USJ(LOOP1)",
                    "description": "Shah Alam - USJ"
                },
                "checkpoints": {
                    "pkCheckpointId": "58c0f7b2-550e-4cff-a9d5-a817c81ad55a",
                    "company": {
                        "pkCompanyId": "f77819c5-97b8-41be-a745-33f907353e9e",
                        "name": null,
                        "phone": null
                    },
                    "section": {
                        "pkSectionId": "2cd43029-71aa-43a4-8aa2-7e2fbf1ecb1f",
                        "company": null,
                        "sectionNumber": null,
                        "sectionName": "C6",
                        "description": null,
                        "region": null,
                        "mapcenter": null,
                        "mapzoom": null
                    },
                    "cardinalDirection": {
                        "key": 293,
                        "value": "N/A",
                        "description": "Tidak Berkenaan"
                    },
                    "locationType": {
                        "key": 51,
                        "value": "Toll Plaza",
                        "description": null
                    },
                    "kilometerMarker": 4.50,
                    "latitude": "3.06000000",
                    "longtitude": "101.56000000",
                    "name": "Ebor (S) T/P"
                },
                "sequence": 8
            },
            {
                "pkRondaLoopCheckpointsId": "95aaae00-ba04-4d75-a1ec-366c58cd21a3",
                "rondaLoop": {
                    "pkRondaLoopId": "42ef5505-e739-45f1-bff3-194d9e1329d5",
                    "company": {
                        "pkCompanyId": "f77819c5-97b8-41be-a745-33f907353e9e",
                        "name": null,
                        "phone": null
                    },
                    "section": {
                        "pkSectionId": "2cd43029-71aa-43a4-8aa2-7e2fbf1ecb1f",
                        "company": null,
                        "sectionNumber": null,
                        "sectionName": "C6",
                        "description": null,
                        "region": null,
                        "mapcenter": null,
                        "mapzoom": null
                    },
                    "name": "SHA-USJ(LOOP1)",
                    "description": "Shah Alam - USJ"
                },
                "checkpoints": {
                    "pkCheckpointId": "8404710d-05ab-497b-8777-443007c6b277",
                    "company": {
                        "pkCompanyId": "f77819c5-97b8-41be-a745-33f907353e9e",
                        "name": null,
                        "phone": null
                    },
                    "section": {
                        "pkSectionId": "2cd43029-71aa-43a4-8aa2-7e2fbf1ecb1f",
                        "company": null,
                        "sectionNumber": null,
                        "sectionName": "C6",
                        "description": null,
                        "region": null,
                        "mapcenter": null,
                        "mapzoom": null
                    },
                    "cardinalDirection": {
                        "key": 293,
                        "value": "N/A",
                        "description": "Tidak Berkenaan"
                    },
                    "locationType": {
                        "key": 51,
                        "value": "Toll Plaza",
                        "description": null
                    },
                    "kilometerMarker": 5.40,
                    "latitude": "3.05000000",
                    "longtitude": "101.57000000",
                    "name": "Seafield T/P"
                },
                "sequence": 7
            },
            {
                "pkRondaLoopCheckpointsId": "98bb4343-a187-411d-a363-ec27a35766f5",
                "rondaLoop": {
                    "pkRondaLoopId": "42ef5505-e739-45f1-bff3-194d9e1329d5",
                    "company": {
                        "pkCompanyId": "f77819c5-97b8-41be-a745-33f907353e9e",
                        "name": null,
                        "phone": null
                    },
                    "section": {
                        "pkSectionId": "2cd43029-71aa-43a4-8aa2-7e2fbf1ecb1f",
                        "company": null,
                        "sectionNumber": null,
                        "sectionName": "C6",
                        "description": null,
                        "region": null,
                        "mapcenter": null,
                        "mapzoom": null
                    },
                    "name": "SHA-USJ(LOOP1)",
                    "description": "Shah Alam - USJ"
                },
                "checkpoints": {
                    "pkCheckpointId": "499254b5-ea65-4b32-8fa2-d36ee77f12b7",
                    "company": {
                        "pkCompanyId": "f77819c5-97b8-41be-a745-33f907353e9e",
                        "name": null,
                        "phone": null
                    },
                    "section": {
                        "pkSectionId": "c179476a-7fa5-4189-9ed0-1abd8ee4f8c2",
                        "company": null,
                        "sectionNumber": null,
                        "sectionName": "C4",
                        "description": null,
                        "region": null,
                        "mapcenter": null,
                        "mapzoom": null
                    },
                    "cardinalDirection": {
                        "key": 293,
                        "value": "N/A",
                        "description": "Tidak Berkenaan"
                    },
                    "locationType": {
                        "key": 51,
                        "value": "Toll Plaza",
                        "description": null
                    },
                    "kilometerMarker": 0.00,
                    "latitude": "3.10000000",
                    "longtitude": "101.55000000",
                    "name": "Shah Alam T/B"
                },
                "sequence": 1
            },
            {
                "pkRondaLoopCheckpointsId": "e63b7424-d3c9-4266-bf30-91db1751b2eb",
                "rondaLoop": {
                    "pkRondaLoopId": "42ef5505-e739-45f1-bff3-194d9e1329d5",
                    "company": {
                        "pkCompanyId": "f77819c5-97b8-41be-a745-33f907353e9e",
                        "name": null,
                        "phone": null
                    },
                    "section": {
                        "pkSectionId": "2cd43029-71aa-43a4-8aa2-7e2fbf1ecb1f",
                        "company": null,
                        "sectionNumber": null,
                        "sectionName": "C6",
                        "description": null,
                        "region": null,
                        "mapcenter": null,
                        "mapzoom": null
                    },
                    "name": "SHA-USJ(LOOP1)",
                    "description": "Shah Alam - USJ"
                },
                "checkpoints": {
                    "pkCheckpointId": "8404710d-05ab-497b-8777-443007c6b277",
                    "company": {
                        "pkCompanyId": "f77819c5-97b8-41be-a745-33f907353e9e",
                        "name": null,
                        "phone": null
                    },
                    "section": {
                        "pkSectionId": "2cd43029-71aa-43a4-8aa2-7e2fbf1ecb1f",
                        "company": null,
                        "sectionNumber": null,
                        "sectionName": "C6",
                        "description": null,
                        "region": null,
                        "mapcenter": null,
                        "mapzoom": null
                    },
                    "cardinalDirection": {
                        "key": 293,
                        "value": "N/A",
                        "description": "Tidak Berkenaan"
                    },
                    "locationType": {
                        "key": 51,
                        "value": "Toll Plaza",
                        "description": null
                    },
                    "kilometerMarker": 5.40,
                    "latitude": "3.05000000",
                    "longtitude": "101.57000000",
                    "name": "Seafield T/P"
                },
                "sequence": 3
            },
            {
                "pkRondaLoopCheckpointsId": "f0afa11b-a2ac-4f27-8b2c-3279f87ddd69",
                "rondaLoop": {
                    "pkRondaLoopId": "42ef5505-e739-45f1-bff3-194d9e1329d5",
                    "company": {
                        "pkCompanyId": "f77819c5-97b8-41be-a745-33f907353e9e",
                        "name": null,
                        "phone": null
                    },
                    "section": {
                        "pkSectionId": "2cd43029-71aa-43a4-8aa2-7e2fbf1ecb1f",
                        "company": null,
                        "sectionNumber": null,
                        "sectionName": "C6",
                        "description": null,
                        "region": null,
                        "mapcenter": null,
                        "mapzoom": null
                    },
                    "name": "SHA-USJ(LOOP1)",
                    "description": "Shah Alam - USJ"
                },
                "checkpoints": {
                    "pkCheckpointId": "df923a70-dd5a-49fa-ad0d-5224106fcbab",
                    "company": {
                        "pkCompanyId": "f77819c5-97b8-41be-a745-33f907353e9e",
                        "name": null,
                        "phone": null
                    },
                    "section": {
                        "pkSectionId": "2cd43029-71aa-43a4-8aa2-7e2fbf1ecb1f",
                        "company": null,
                        "sectionNumber": null,
                        "sectionName": "C6",
                        "description": null,
                        "region": null,
                        "mapcenter": null,
                        "mapzoom": null
                    },
                    "cardinalDirection": {
                        "key": 293,
                        "value": "N/A",
                        "description": "Tidak Berkenaan"
                    },
                    "locationType": {
                        "key": 51,
                        "value": "Toll Plaza",
                        "description": null
                    },
                    "kilometerMarker": 4.30,
                    "latitude": "3.07000000",
                    "longtitude": "101.56000000",
                    "name": "Ebor (U) T/P"
                },
                "sequence": 2
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now I need to fetch the `latitude` and `longitude` of from the `checkpoints` array.
And from these coordinates I can draw it into the map using the `for` loop function which I've defined.

## The hardcoded coordinates in  # `_markerLocations` # array are supposed to be replaced with the lat and lng from the http body #

HERE IS AN ADDITIONAL CODE :-

```
class MapLocationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final MarkerApiService markerApi = MarkerApiService();
  @override
  _MapLocationScreenState createState() => _MapLocationScreenState();
}

class _MapLocationScreenState extends State<MapLocationScreen> {
  final Completer<GoogleMapController> mapController = Completer();
  Map<MarkerId, Marker> markers = <MarkerId, Marker>{};
  final markerKey = GlobalKey();
  final Map<String, Marker> _markers = {};
  final Set<Marker> _markerloop = {};
  final AuthApiService auth = AuthApiService();
  List<LatLng> _latLngs;
  final data = MarkerApiService().getCoordinates();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _latLngs = _parseLatLngsFromJSON(data);
    widget.markerApi.getCoordinates().then((body) {
      print(body);
    });
  }

  List<LatLng> _parseLatLngsFromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> rondaLoopCheckpoints =
        data["body"]["rondaLoopCheckpointsList"];
        List<Marker> latLngData = <Marker>[];
    rondaLoopCheckpoints.forEach((Map<String, dynamic> item) {
      Map<String, dynamic> checkPoint = item["checkpoints"];
      latLngData.add(Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId('loop_route'),
        position: LatLng(checkPoint['latitude'], checkPoint['longitude'])
      ));
    });
    return latLngData;
  }
}

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        GoogleMap(
          initialCameraPosition:
              CameraPosition(target: LatLng(3.082519, 101.592201), zoom: 15.0),
          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          mapType: MapType.normal,
          markers: _markerloop,
          // Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
        ),
        Positioned(
          bottom: 50,
          right: 0,
          child: FlatButton(
            child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.mapMarkedAlt),
            onPressed: () => _initMarkers(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Below is the HTTP request:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class MarkerApiService with ChangeNotifier {
  static final MarkerApiService _singleton = MarkerApiService._internal();
  Map body;

  factory MarkerApiService() {
    return _singleton;
  }
  MarkerApiService._internal();

  //get Token
  Future<String> get token async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.getString('token');
  }

  //save token
  Future<bool> _persistToken(token) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.setString('token', token);
  }

  Future<bool> _saveToken(String token) async {
    if (token != null) {
      await _persistToken(token);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getCoordinates() async {
    //save
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final token = prefs.getString('token');
    final String url =
        'http://192.168.200.65:8081/rest/auth/getDetailMobileUser';
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000));

    final res = await http.post(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": token,
    });
    body = json.decode(res.body);
    Map<String,dynamic> latLngData = await getCoordinates();
    return body;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep this where your http request is getting executed.

```
final Response response = await http.get("Your URL");

final String body = response.body;
// your list.
List<LatLng> _latLngs = _parseLatLngsFromJSON(jsonDecode(body));
```

Following is the method that will parse your JSON.

```
List<LatLng> _parseLatLngsFromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> rondaLoopCheckpoints =
      data["body"]["rondaLoopCheckpointsList"];
      List<LatLng> latLngData = <LatLng>[];
  rondaLoopCheckpoints.forEach((Map<String, dynamic> item) {
    Map<String, dynamic> checkPoint = item["checkpoints"];
    latLngData.add(LatLng(
      num.tryParse(checkPoint["latitude"]),
      num.tryParse(checkPoint["longtitude"]),
    ));
  });
  return latLngData;
}
```

Now you have the list of LatLng that you wanted.

In case you want demo, [***see this demo***](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/7bf0f9ad7dff0c18059a1870017a4cf0)
I hope it helps, let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: First of all, thank you for taking the time to make a demo for me . And I've encountered an error while taking the code . I've done a `Future<Map<String,dynamic>>` for my Http post method and at the the code it return an error at `_latLngs = _parseLatLngsFromJSON(data);`

Comment: Error  -  `The argument type 'Future<Map<String, dynamic>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'`

Comment: Have you called await on your future before taking value from it ?? There is the problem.. if you wont do map = await future you will get this error..

Comment: There is no code when you open this link, just the default template..

Comment: Map<String,dynamic>> latLngData = await getCoordinates(); call your method like this. And you won't get that error.

Comment: Where shall I include this line?

Comment: Exactly where are you getting the error ?? Call await there.. you are expecting Map but just because you are not calling await you are getting Future<Map>.. I hope you are getting my point

Comment: Here is the code snippet. The red lines are the errors [code snippet](https://ibb.co/6XLvMHy)

Comment: 1. Return type of your method should be List<Marker> because you are returning List<Marker>. 2. What is the type of "data" that you are passing to _parseLatLngToJSON ?? 3. Caution: while creating Marker you are passing latitude to longitude

Comment: I've edited the question and posted additional code